# How to sync Google contacts, Mac OS Address Book, and iPhone contacts - Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, address-book, google-contacts

I'm successfully syncing Snow Leopard iCal, Google Calendar and iPhone Calendar. However, when I try what looks like the same setup for contacts, I end up having duplicate contacts on the iPhone.

What is the correct setup to sync these three contact lists?

Thanks and regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the Google Exchange account on your iPhone syncing contacts and iTunes syncing your Mac's Address Book as well.
Go to your iPhone in iTunes and turn off 'Sync Address Book Contacts' (it's at the top of the Info tab).

Comment: No, I don't have contacts being sync'ed from Google on the iPhone, just calendars. So if I do as you suggest, Google contacts don't get sync'd with anything. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest that you use Exchange to sync your contacts and calendars on your phone (and turn off 'Sync Address Book') and use the built in Google sync functionality in Address Book and iCal on your desktop. That way you'll get all the benefits of cloud syncing and you should be able to completely avoid any issues with duplicate entries.